# EXCEL - Checking cell based on value of another cell on another tab

Tags: excel

I'm having the following issue:

[image]

On the tab "Auditierte Normelemente" I would like to have an overview of which elements of an audition are being covered.

So for example if the topic "4. Kontext der Organisation" (B7) got covered in the year 18-19 (Column C), I would like a X to appear there (C7).

This information will come from another tab (2018-2019 PCW, in blue) which looks like this:

[image]

So, if "4. Kontext der Organisation" is found on column G or on column M or on column S, the X should appear on the cell C7 of the tab "Auditierte Normelemente" and so on for the other topics on column B and later also for the years 19-20 and 20-21.

Do you guys have an idea for this? I've tried the IF function but it gets huge and very complex and doesn't work very precisely.

I would appreciate any help since I couln't find a similar case in the previous questions.

Thanks a lot!

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

In 'Auditierte Normelemente'!C7,

```
=if(or(countif('2018-2019 PCW'!g:g, b7), countif('2018-2019 PCW'!m:m, b7), countif('2018-2019 PCW'!s:s, b7)), "x", "")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that's how it looks like now: =IF(OR(COUNTIF(' 2018-2019 PCW'!$G$5:$G$26;B7)>0; COUNTIF(' 2018-2019 PCW'!$M$5:$M$26;B7)>0; COUNTIF(' 2018-2019 PCW'!$S$5:$S$26;B7)>0);"X";"")